# My flutter app can't run on Windows 7 SP1 64bit

Tags: windows, flutter, windows-7-x64, flutter-windows

I'm flutter developer, and some of my clients still using Windows 7.

According to the [docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/reference/supported-platforms), flutter deployed apps supports Windows 7, But when I try to run my app on Windows 7, I faced this issue:

[image: flutter error on windows 7]

I try manual adding missing dll files, but still not works:

[image: flutter error on windows 7]

Any solution?

Comment: Is your app depending on any desktop-only package, like [bitsdojo_window](https://pub.dev/packages/bitsdojo_window)? I had a similar issue once, when a package did not support all Windows version supported by flutter itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone facing this issue or similar issue, this is caused by one of your packages.

Yes, flutter apps support windows 7 but some packages which imports native windows codes or dlls, doesn't support win 7

For me it was caused by [local_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth) package which support only for windows 10 and later:
[image]

You can fix this issue by these steps:

1. Build a windows release of your app by `flutter build windows --release`
2. Open `\build\windows\runner\Release` folder of your project.
3. You can see all of your app `.dlls`, search every `.dll` file name and see it's package documents and find that package which doesn't supports windows 7.
4. Remove that package from `pubspec.yaml` and build your app again.